# How to fade in appended HTML with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line of code:

```
var html = "...";
$("#id_name").append(html).fadeIn("slow");
```

This causes the entire div #id_name to fade in.  I want *only* the *appended HTML* to fade in.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo("#id_name").hide().append(html).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 2):

you'd have to make sure the variable "html" is a jquery object first , and present in the DOM.

So you'd typically fire a callback function, fired when the append() is effective.

example:

```
$("#id_name").append(html,function(){
 $(html).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work (assuming the `html` var is a snippet of html code) and may be a bit more readable:

```
$(html).appendTo('#id_name').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```